# Python.h: No such file or directory

Tags: arch-linux, compiling, python

I'm trying to build omniORB 4.1.6 under Arch Linux. When I type `make`, here is the message:

```
../../../../../src/tool/omniidl/cxx/idlpython.cc:188:26: fatal error:  python3.3/Python.h: No such file or directory
#  include PYTHON_INCLUDE
```

I'm sure both python3 and python2 were installed, and I can remember last time I was tring to do the same thing under Linux Mint I met the same problem. That time, I used this command to solve the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

However, it seems Arch doesn't separate python-dev with python. I checked my `/usr` and found Python.h under `/usr/include/python3.3m`, so what should I do now?

Comment: Did you run `./configure` before running `make`? That header file is there on Ubuntu 12.04 as well. You can try to make a link in `/usr/include` from `python3.3` to `python3.3m`

Comment: I did run './configure' before running `make`. In addition, after making the link from `python3.3` to `python3.3m`, it seems this question was sloved, however I'm facing farther problem thus the building failed again...Thanks to @don_crissti, I decided to download it from repos directly, I just realized this method...

Comment: it is **python-devel** in some distributions, like redhat, fedora, centos etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally running

```
./configure
```

before running `make` should set up things correctly, but in this fall that seems not to be the case.

Python 3.3.X puts its header files in `.../include/Python3.3m`, whereas 2.7.x uses  `.../include/python2.7` (without any suffix), maybe `omniORB` is not aware (yet) of that suffix `m`.

You can make a link from python3.3m to python3.3 using:

```
cd /usr/include
ln -s python3.3m python3.3
```

and retry the build process ( this assumes python3.3 was configured using `--prefix=/usr`, adapt the `cd` as necessary).

Comment: I had a same problem on Arch. This was really helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have installed the python-dev package and are still getting errors;

I thought the `PYTHON` parameter on the configure command line was the directory of the `Python.h` file ... nope, use the path to the interpreter.

I created and used a "build" directory in omniORB;

```
cd "omniORB install loc"; mkdir build; cd build; ...
```

You can give the location of Python as part of the configure command line.

```
../configure ... PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
```

In my case, with OmniORB installed in `/opt` and going to be using `/opt` as its home:

```
../configure --prefix=/opt/omniORB.build.4.3.0 --with-omniORB-config=/opt/omniORB.build.4.3.0/omniORB.cfg --with-omniNames-logdir=$HOME/logs PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
```